# Creating a multiple choice question in LaTeX

Tags: latex, multiple-choice

I am trying to make a multiple choice question in LaTeX. I am a little confused as to whether

> `\begin{question}{MultipleChoice`}

is something that LaTeX can handle by default or do I need extra packages, descriptions, ect...(I am super new to LaTex).

That being said, if I run the following code I do not get a multiple choice question, but rather an error that says  'lonely \item -  perhaps missing a list environment.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience!

```
  %%%% ENVIRONMENT FOR LIST FOR QUESTIONS LIST %%%%
    \newenvironment{questions}{ %   %%%% Begin preliminary environment code
        \begin{list}{ %     %%%% Begin list item label code
            \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}:
        }{ %    %%%% Begin list item body code
            \usecounter{qcounter}
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{1in}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.25in}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5ex}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{2em}
        } %%%%% End list item body code
    }{        %%%%% Begin wrapup environment code
        \end{list}
    } %%%%% End wrapup environment code

    %%%% ENVIRONMENT FOR A SINGLE QUESTION %%%%
    \newenvironment{question}{\item{}}{}



    \begin{question}{MultipleChoice}
    \qutext{$3\log x-2\log y=$}
    \choice*{$\log\left(\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{y^2}\right)$}
    \choice{$\log(x^3y^2)$}
    \choice{$\log(3x-2y)$}
    \choice{$\log(x^3-y^2)$}
    \end{question}
```

Comment: You might want to post this on the TeX StackExchange (http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a smiple example using the exam class:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question [3] What is the right choice of the following choices?
    \begin{choices}
      \choice first choice
      \choice second choice
    \end{choices}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This will produce something like this:
[image]

For more details see section: 5 in the [exam class](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf) guide.

Answer (score 5):

Better use the [exam class](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf)

Comment: I got Forbidden on the first three tries. The fourth was successful.  You might want to add that `texdoc exam` gives the installations current documentation (lots of old installs out there; ubuntu I'm looking at you!)

Answer (score 0):

Exam class can be used alongside some changes.

[Here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) is the doc for Exam *class*.

And customize it using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273797/multiple-choice-question-type-setting-for-options).

**Remember**: This is a class *not a package*. Read the doc carefully before you go to type anything.